# assign start_date for dag from dag config in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Is there any way to set dag start_date from the airflow dag Config set in UI?.
I want to assign the dag start_date to a value from dag config if present, else a default value.

Below is the code i have tried:

`conf_start_date = '{{ dag_run.conf["start_date"] if dag_run else datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=-367) }} '`

I am using this conf_start_date for defining dag:

```
dag = DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        end_date=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=-2),
        start_date=conf_start_date,
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        catchup=True,
        default_args=args,
        concurrency=100,
        max_active_runs=15
    )
```

I am getting error:
**Broken DAG: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'.**

Note: I am using Python 3.8

Comment: It's bad practice to have dynamic start date so please explain why you think this is necessary

Comment: As @Elad said, it is not a good practice to set a dynamic start date.

Since you have setup `catchup = True`, first run will take place  at 2020-06-05, but after midnight you cannot rerun this batch because start would change to 2020-06-06 and this run would have execution date before dag start date. Upon rerun, the execution will remain scheduled state. This will become worse as days will pass. You will have runs in your airflow dag which you cannot rerun.

On the other hand, if you set `catchup=False`, you can use any static date from past and it would make no difference in any case.

Comment: And btw, where is dag_run?

Comment: @Relic16 `dag_run` is an Airflow macro which references a `DagRun` object.  Typically it's accessed and used when triggering a DAG programmatically.  Some further detail [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#passing-parameters-when-triggering-dags)

Comment: @Elad i have data from various source and i want to reuse the dag as except for start_date everything else remains same for the sources. So I wanted to fetch start date from config

Comment: For that purpose you probably have better options than changing the start_date. I still don't see why you need to change it.